# How do I obtain the standard errors for Ornstein Uhlenbeck parameter estimates?

Tags: regression, standard-error, stochastic-processes

I have used least squares estimation to obtain estimates for parameters to be used in Ornstein Uhlenbeck process. Now, I would like to compute the standard errors of estimates.

$=(−)+$ (Ornstein Uhlenbeck process and parameters to be estimated)

The regression is as follows:

$S(t+1)=a*S(t)+b+$

The estimates for parameters are obtained from the regression coefficients as follows:

$=−(ln)/Δ, =/(1−)$

and

$=sd() * \sqrt{2/(1−^{−2Δ})}$

I can obtain the standard errors for a and b, but how would I be able to obtain standard errors for the parameters?

Any help is greatly appreciated, I apologize the messy layout of formulas.

Answer (score 0):

If you are reporting to physicists or chemicists, I would recommend the Gaussian error propagation law, because that is what they usually apply in such cases:
$$(\Delta f)^2 = \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial a} \Delta a\right)^2 + \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial b} \Delta b\right)^2 + \ldots$$
If you are reporting to statisticians, a resampling method like the bootstrap or the jacknife might raise fewer eyebrows ;-) The jackknife is easier and yields reproducibale results, whilst the bootstrap yields a random (albeit not much different) result.